# solve layout difference between browsers

Tags: css, layout, browser, offset

[image]

I've created this little menu for a search/login form...
There's this lenguage selector that doesn't work correctly, is there something i do wrong in the CSS or in the HTML? I've set the menù with the flags using a position:absolute; and the margin-top (i also tried with the "top" attribute) to position it over the flag, but the layout on mozilla firefox is still offset.

Is there an attribute that i can give to the CSS that is read in the same way in every Browser?
Or i've to use some javascript to get the browser of the user?

This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>ZapPeers</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index_tmp.css"/><link rel="image_src" href="/favlogo.png"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/index_tmp.js"></script></head>
<body onload="textfocus()"><div id="head"><div id="noise"></div><div id="body"><img src="src.png" alt="" name="logo" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="ind" id="logo"/><div class="ind" id="win"><form id="formzap" name="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"><input type="text" name="textfield" class="ind" id="textzap" onkeypress="fadefx.init('noise', 1)" onblur="fadefx.init('noise', 0)" autocomplete="off" autofocus/><button type="submit" name="button" class="ind" id="buttonzap" value=""></button></form><div id="user"><form id="formlog" name="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off"><input type="text" name="textfield" class="ind textlog" placeholder="e-mail address" autocomplete="off"/><input type="password" name="textfield" class="ind textlog" placeholder="password" autocomplete="off"/><button type="submit" name="button" class="ind" id="buttonlog" value=""></button></form><ul id="flag"><li><img src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="eng" /><ul id="list"><li><a href="willkommen.html"><img title="Deutsch" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="ger" /></a></li><li><a href="bienvenido.html"><img title="Español" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="spa" /></a></li><li><a href="bienvenue.html"><img title="Français" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="fra" /></a></li><li><a href="benvenuto.html"><img title="Italiano" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="ita" /></a></li><li><a href="yokoso.html"><img title="日本人" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="jpn" /></a></li><li><a href="huanying.html"><img title="中国的" src="src.png" alt="" name="" width="1" height="1" border="0" class="flag" id="chi" /></a></li></ul></li></ul><p>Sign Up • Forgot User/Pass? • About</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

This is the CSS

```
body{background:url(/background.png);font:13px bold Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;color: #071c28;}
.ind{background:url(/index_tmp.png);}
img#logo{width:630px;height:225px;background-position:0 -126px;margin-top:8px;}
div#head{width:640px;height:360px;margin:10% auto 0 auto;text-align:center;}
div#win{width:392px;height:81px;margin-left:114px;margin-right:114px;margin-top:1px;background-position:-126px 0;padding:10px;}
div#user{width:392px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
div#flags{width:16px;height:16px;margin-left:10px;margin-top:6px;float:right;}
div#body{position:relative;width:640px;height:360px;z-index:10;}
div#noise{position:absolute;width:640px;height:360px;background-image:url(./noise.gif);z-index:1;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity='0');}
form{padding-top:3px;}
input{border:0px;vertical-align:top;padding:4px;opacity:0.75;filter:alpha(opacity=75);margin-right:4px;}input:hover{opacity:0.9;filter:alpha(opacity=90);}input:focus{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);outline:none;}
button{border:0px;margin-right:1px;}button:focus{outline:none;}
input#textzap{background-position:0 -105px;width:310px;height:12px;}
input.textlog{background-position: -336px -105px;width:149px;height:12px;}
button#buttonzap{background-position:0 0;width:58px;height:21px;}
button#buttonzap:hover,button#buttonzap:focus{background-position:0 -21px;}
button#buttonzap:active{background-position:0 -42px;}
button#buttonlog{background-position:-63px 0;width:58px;height:21px;}
button#buttonlog:hover,button#buttonlog:focus{background-position:-63px -21px;}
button#buttonlog:active{background-position:-63px -42px;}
p{display:block;margin:0;margin-top:6px;font-weight: bold;text-align:left;}
a:link{text-decoration:none;}a:visited{text-decoration:none;}a:hover{text-decoration:none;}a:active{text-decoration:none;}

ul,li,li a{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:relative;display:inline;width:16px;height:16px;float:inherit;}
ul#flag{width:20px;height:20px;margin-top:5px;margin-right:10px;margin-left:6px;float:left;}
ul#list{left:-3px;float:left;display:none;width:120px;height:22px;background:url(./flag_tmp.png);padding:1px;padding-top:20px;margin-top:-18px;}
ul li{margin:2px;}
li:hover ul#list{display:block;}
img.flag{background:url(/flag_tmp.png);width:16px;height:16px;}
#ita{background-position:0 -43px;}
#spa{background-position:-16px -43px;}
#fra{background-position:-32px -43px;}
#eng{background-position:-48px -43px;}
#ger{background-position:-64px -43px;}
#jpn{background-position:-80px -43px;}
#chi{background-position:-96px -43px;}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#1b3b4d;}input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder,input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#315e77;}
input:-moz-placeholder{color:#1b3b4d;}input:hover:-moz-placeholder,input:focus:-moz-placeholder{color:#315e77;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#1b3b4d;}input:hover:-ms-input-placeholder,input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#315e77;}
```

I didn't add this before 'cause i deleted every space in the HTML, i saw that also that are interpreted in different ways between the browsers.

-------------------------[EDIT]-------------------------

```
var BrowserDetect = {
   init: function () {
      if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))alert("firefox")
      if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent))alert("MSIE")
      if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))alert("Opera")
      if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))alert("Chrome")
      if (/Apple[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))alert("Safari")
   }
}
```

I've tried this to detect in few lines the browser (from the most used).
But it doesn't seems to work...
I can use this to change the layout difference as latest solution.

Comment: HTML structure and CSS will be preferable to answer this question.

Comment: Adding `* { margin:0; padding:0; } ` is a good start to getting the browsers to have the same layout. It certainly doesn't fix everything but it's still worth it.

Comment: I can't see any difference... if you post your actual markup and css someone will be able to help though. Also, there is a way to target firefox only: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/ but that should be the very last resort.

Comment: All four of your images look exactly the same and you've shown us no code.   Please fix your OP before it's closed.

Comment: All main browsers are using different render engines. Unless you use images you won't have the same display in every browser. There will be always some miss behaviors :)

Comment: @Sparky There is a difference, see flags in mozilas part of image

Comment: @GomatoX, thanks, but the only point of my comment was to get **the OP** to edit & improve his question.

Answer (score 0):

Some stylesheet can help you

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

this reset browser differences

but you need to adjust for specific rules of what you need

You can also add classes on elements like body tag dynamically with jQuery and isolate rules

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I won't forget, i'm trying it right now. EDIT: the problem is partially solved, the offset is smaller, this stylesheet surelly will help... But some difference are still there between the browsers... Thanks again anyway!! a really usefull stylesheet for my website! :)

Comment: This is not a "magic bullet" solution.  If you don't know what you're doing... it's just a starting point.  And if you do know what you're doing, there's no need to reset every single element.

Comment: I know, and in fact i don't know what to do, this is why i said this is a usefull stylesheet, i can work on from this, i found a javascript (that do not use jQuery or other SDKs) to idenfity the browser and the OS, i can use that with this stylesheet as starting point. if i manage to solve the issue i'll post a SDK-free solution.